# NightmareJS Scripts Never Return?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

Consider the following NightmareJS script...

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');

var yandex = new Nightmare()
    .viewport(1000,1000)
    .useragent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36")
    .goto('https://yandex.com/')
    .run(function(err, nightmare) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

It just hangs and never returns me to the prompt. Actions are performed. I can take screenshots and do other things but the node process never ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have troubles if you are using Nightmare like that. Async/await solves lots of problems when using Nightmare.js

```
async function test(url){
  try{
    const nightmare = Nightmare({show:true})
    await nightmare.useragent(userAgentOption)
    const response = await nightmare.goto(url)
    await nightmare.wait(2000)
    const evaluated = await nightmare.evaluate(()=>{
       return document.querySelector("input").innerHTML
    })  
  }catch(err){
    throw new Error(err)    
  }  
}
```

You can log inside the function after each step to see where it fails.

Even better option is to use WebStorm as it works very well on debugging Nightmare.js

Debug solutions like **iron-node** are **Electron** based and they won't work with Nightmare.js code

Now you can call the code like that:

```
test("https://yandex.com").then(console.log).catch(console.log)
```

Comment: I'm using WebStorm but I was just running it from the terminal. What's the cause of it hanging like tha (The troubles)t? The documentation doesn't mention this issue from what I've seen.

Comment: Try add this as env variable - "DEBUG=nightmare*" in Webstorm or prepend it to your terminal command

Comment: I've got the nightmare API working thanks to your example but it still never exits. I tried adding the debug flag.

Comment: Nevermind, nightmare.end works. Had to keep it within the function.